# Retrieving Image from a URL and adding to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, datatable

I need to display an Image in my ASP.NET ListView and I'm getting the Image through a URL. I need to get the Image from the URL and store in a DataTable row so that I can assign it as the image source.

This is what I have so far and I got stuck and lost at the end, what am I missing?

```
String url = "http://www.URL_GOES_HERE...";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Picture", typeof(byte[]));
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
......
```

Comment: You seem to be missing an understanding of HTML. What HTML element would you like to have rendered to display your image?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm trying to display the Image in a Image control?

Comment: Your datatable column type should note be a `byte[]`. Like you said in your description, you need to get the URL, which means it's a string. You don't need to bother with a `BitmapImage` either. You put the URL in the datatable, bind the datatable to your ListView, and in your ListView you'll have an image field, which you'll wire up to the column in your datatable that contains the URL.

Comment: wow really, so the Image field automatically retrieves the image through the URL and displays it? @mason

Comment: @MWUser No. The Image control will have the URL of the image, and so it'll render some HTML like `<img src="myimg.png" />`. When the browser renders the page it'll fetch the URL from the `src` attribute of the `img` tag, go to that URL and download the image and display it

Comment: That's your problem. You believe in "image controls" and don't understand the `<img>` tag in HTML. You don't send a bunch of bytes to the browser and it then displays the image. You have to include something like `<img src="/img/myimage.jpg">`. The browser then fetches the image from the URL and displays it.

Comment: alright alright thank you, I did that and its okay now (Y) @JohnSaunders